# Scala PlayFramework 2.3 setting up the configuration in a view

Tags: scala, playframework

I am using PlayFramework 2.3 and when I compile the project I am getting this error

> value appilication is not a member of object play.Play
>   [error] @appStaticUrl = @{play.Play.appilication().configuration().getString("app.staticUrl")}

I understand what it means but actually I am using the same method in other projects and it works. Also this error is thrown by 2 of the 4 lines I have in the view

```
@appStaticUrl = @{play.Play.appilication().configuration().getString("app.staticUrl")}
@appVersion = @{play.Play.appilication().configuration().getString("app.version")}
@minPosfix = @{play.Play.application().configuration().getString("app.static.minPosfix")}
@appBaseUrl = @{play.Play.application().configuration().getString("app.baseUrl")}
```

I am not sure why is happening and how may I solve this

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mistyped `application` in the first two lines.

Answer (score 1):

You have `appilication` written instead of `application` in the first and second line